# Provide password for running a script inside another script as different user

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sudo

Imagine you run script as user A: ***sudo -u A ./script.sh***
Inside that *script.sh* we have a line that calls another script *script2.sh* with a different user B: ***sudo -u B ./script2.sh***. Now I get prompted to enter a password for user B. Is there any way to provide that password uppon call?

P.S. I know all the security breaches it can create. Please do not mention me that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you have option for that. But that password you have to provide at the time of executing the script or hard coded it in the script itself. Try with the below example:-

```
echo 'passwordofB' | sudo -u B -S ./script2.sh
```

Also you can do it like:-

```
 sudo -u A ./script.sh passwordofB #as a command line parameter
```

now inside `script.sh`:-

```
echo $1 | sudo -u B -S ./script2.sh
```

You are executing another script `sudo -u B ./script2.sh` from script `./script.sh` right? So change that line with `echo $1 | sudo -u B -S ./script2.sh` and run your first script as `sudo -u A ./script.sh passwordofB` where `passwordofB` is the password for user 'B'

Comment: I dont see the part where you specify the user B :)

Something like:
echo 'passwordofB' | sudo -S -u B ./script2.sh

Because sudo -S will execute as root by default.

Comment: you are executing another script `sudo -u B ./script2.sh` from script `./script.sh` right? So change that line with `echo $1 | sudo -S ./script2.sh` and run your first script as `sudo -u A ./script.sh passwordofB` where `passwordofB` is the password for user 'B'

Comment: Hi, I have modified my answer.

Comment: Yes! It worked. I just checket it with echo '123' | sudo -u AAA -S whoami and got AAA printed. Nice. Thank you!

Comment: @LaimonasSutkus, happy that its works for you. Wish you all the very best :-)